# Remove the Alphabet in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi I'm new in Crystal Reports, I'm using Crystal Reports 2008 and I would like to know if how can I remove the alphabet characters in string and only the numbers will remain. Is there function for this?

example: Point 231 / Point 323 / USP 342
output: 231 / 323 / 342

Thanks,
Captain16

Comment: Have you considered using a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following formula

```
stringvar str;
stringvar str1;
numbervar counter;
numbervar leng;

leng := len({Your_Field});
if leng>0 then
 (
    for counter := 1 to leng do
    (
        If (Mid({Your_Field}, counter, 1)) in "a" to "z" Then
        (
            str1:=str1 + Mid({Your_Field}, counter, 1)
        )
        else
        (
            str := str + Mid({Your_Field}, counter, 1)
        )
    );
str
 )
```

Here the `str` will get the non-alphabets and `str1` will get you only the alphabets from the given string. `{Your_Field}` can be your field or parameter which contains the string. And by printing `str` alphabets can be removed...
`231 / 323 / 342` this is the output I'm getting for your given input !
Hope this helps, Try and get back with results !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment on Hariharan Anbazhagan's code (I don't have enough reputation it seems).  It's good code but I would add LCASE to catch all the captial letters.

```
If LCASE(Mid({?sample}, counter, 1)) in "a" to "z" Then
```

There's also a IsNumeric() function if you want to identify just the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your good suggestion !! But by default my code removes uppercase alphabets. The asker Captain16 wants to remove only alphabets from the given string. Thus it can be achieved thru my code. But can u help me in adding `NOT` in  `If (Mid({Your_Field}, counter, 1)) in "a" to "z" Then` code ?? unnecessary i'm using else case since i cant use `NOT` in `if`.

Comment: I got the chance to try your code... Nice!  I didn't know it understood upper and lower case.  I guess if you want to get rid of the ELSE, you could do `If NOT(Mid({Your_Field}, counter, 1) in "a" to "z") Then`.  But I think yours is fine, you can see what you removed.