# How to remove html tags from crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I did use htmltexteditor now the problem is when i creating the crystal report & try to fetched data from database within dataset it shows data with html tags. & its also not showing complete data & not goto second page as well.

i'll try to use regex.replace but cant find where should i use this?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {int admin_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["admin_id"].ToString());
                DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
                SqlDataAdapter sdp = new SqlDataAdapter("spsslct", con);
                sdp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sdp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", admin_id);
                sdp.Fill(ds.DataTable1);
                CrystalReport3 cr = new CrystalReport3();
                cr.SetDataSource(ds);   
                CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = cr;
                CrystalReportViewer2.DataBind();
            }
```

I know regex.replace use but cant find where should i use this?

Comment: is your data stored as HTML tags in database and what is your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways - Interpret HTML as it is

1. Right click on the field
2. Select Format Field
3. Select Paragraph Tab

Change the 'Text Interpretation to "HTML Text"

For replacing (not Regex in Crystal) you need to add formula and use that formula in Report instead of directly using the field itself.
Follow this link :[Stackoverflow answer to remove alphabet/symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151683/remove-the-alphabet-in-crystal-report)

Comment: yeah thanks its work! But its apply html also? can you tell me how to remove it?